# How to set up host and v-host properly for 2 different folders?

Tags: .htaccess, localhost, apache2, host, vhosts

Hi i have zero knowledge about setting up domain and stuff, all i did was search the net. And i think i do not get the correct keyword from my search since i just can't find the correct answer for my problem.
now i need your help guys. please, i want them to work those 2 domains and their respective DocumentRoots

this is my host file setup

```
127.0.0.1   mydomain.com
127.0.0.1   mydomain.net
```

this is my vhost file setup

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/mydomain-com"
    ServerName mydomain.com
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/mydomain-com">
          Options All
          AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>


  <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/mydomain-net"
    ServerName mydomain.net
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/mydomain-net">
          Options All
          AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

but when i go to mydomain.net it goes to mydomain.com it seems only mydomain.com is working

this is my htaccess file for both

```
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

Comment: im on linux ubuntu if that helps

Comment: Are you really sure that you send a request to `mydomain.net` and not to `www.mydomain.net`? Both are _different_ hosts and the _first_ virtual host defined in an apache http server acts as a default host processing all requests to hosts not explicitly configured.

Comment: thank you for commenting, yes i am sure that i typed mydomain.net and not www.mydomain.net. What i also tried is to restart apache and restart my pc. i'm now thinking of reinstalling my apache.

Comment: also i uncomment this already in httpd.conf -> Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: Reinstalling a package never ever really resolved an issue. That is playing a guessing game.

Comment: The ubuntu apache http server package comes with a configuration file layout splitting the virtual hosts into separate files _and_ using a ``sites-enabled`` folder where hosts are enabled by creating a symbolic link. Are you sure you did that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason but, when i reinstall xampp and include core files now its working just fine.
I assume the previous developer played around the config files and messed it up. geez.
without proper investigation of the real problem, this really is not the correct answer but i would like to close this since i'm all good now.